# jsftp ls operation umlauts are wrong

Tags: node.js, ftp

im using the jsftp library and I have a problem with the ls operation when the directory contains filenames with umlauts. The umlauts are not correct when I get the filename.

The FTP protocol uses 7Bit-ASCII encoding but how could I encode it to an UTF8 string so the umlauts are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of the jsftp framework fixed this problem. So it is woking fine now.
See: https://github.com/sergi/jsftp/issues/119